In a regular space with a $\sigma$-locally finite network, is every closed set a $G_\delta$?
In a regular space with a $\sigma$-locally finite network, is every closed set a $G_\delta$?
I'm inclined to think so based upon the basic argument of Theorem 2.8 here, but there are a few moving parts that aren't immediately obvious to me (maybe something subtle happens with a $\sigma$-locally finite network vs a $\sigma$-closure preserving network?), so a direct proof would be appreciated.

Let $\mathcal N = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathcal N_n$ be a network, such that each $\mathcal N_n$ is locally finite.
Then for each n, $\{\overline{N}: N \in  \mathcal N_n\} $ is locally finite, and
$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \{\overline{N}: N \in  \mathcal N_n\}$
is a network, since $X$ is regular.
Hence, we may assume that each $N \in \mathcal N$ is closed.
Of course, each closed set is $G_\delta$, iff each open set is $F_\sigma$.
Thus, let $U$ be an open set of $X$.
For $n \in \mathbb N$, let
$\mathcal M_n = \{N \in \mathcal N_n: N \subset U\}$.
Since $\mathcal N_n$ is locally finite,
$M_n = \bigcup \mathcal M_n$ is closed.
Since $\mathcal N$ is a network, $U = \bigcup \{N \in \mathcal N: N \subset U\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} M_n$ is $F_\sigma$.

Details on some lemmas that @Ulli used implicitly, shown here for convenience:
Lemma 1. If $\mathcal N$ is locally finite, then $\bigcup\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\}=\overline{\bigcup\mathcal N}$.
Proof. $\overline N\subseteq\overline{\bigcup\mathcal N}$ and thus $\bigcup\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\}\subseteq\overline{\bigcup\mathcal N}$ is immediate. Then given a limit point $x$ of $\bigcup\mathcal N$, there exists some neighborhood that intersects only members of some finite $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal N$. As every neighborhood of the limit point $x$ intersects $\bigcup\mathcal N$, every neighborhood must intersect $\bigcup\mathcal F$, so $x\in\overline{\bigcup\mathcal F}=\bigcup\{\overline F:F\in\mathcal F\}\subseteq\bigcup\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\}$.
Lemma 2. If $\mathcal N$ is locally finite, then $\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\}$ is locally finite.
Proof. Given a point $x$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ that intersects only members of some finite $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal N$. It follows that $V=U\setminus\overline{\bigcup\mathcal N\setminus\mathcal F}=U\setminus\bigcup\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\setminus\mathcal F\}$ is an open set that intersects only members of the finite collection $\{\overline F:F\in\mathcal F\}$. Furthermore $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$: for each $N\in\mathcal N\setminus\mathcal F$, $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ missing $N$, so $x\not\in\overline N$.
Lemma 3. If $\mathcal N$ is a network for a regular space, then $\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\}$ is a network as well.
Proof. Given an open set $U$, for each point $x\in U$ choose $U_x$ open with $x\in U_x\subseteq\overline{U_x}\subseteq U$. Then choose $\mathcal N_x\subseteq\mathcal N$ such that $\bigcup\mathcal N_x=U_x$. Finally, consider $\{\overline{N}:N\in\bigcup_{x\in U}\mathcal N_x\}\subseteq\{\overline N:N\in\mathcal N\}$, and note $U=\bigcup\{\overline{N}:N\in\bigcup_{x\in U}\mathcal N_x\}$.
